# AUTOINCREMENT column field asks for an input value

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I've created a database with an autoincremented field:

```
filecur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS File_Data (_FID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, UID INTEGER(1000000), FileName varchar2 (15), Date_ varchar2 (15))")
filecur.execute("insert into File_Data values (?, ?, ?)", (uid, filename, today))
```

However, when I try to insert values in this table, I get an error that says that I've supplied only 3 values in a table with 4 fields. Isn't autoincrement supposed to work on its own, or am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Maybe you wrongly provided the `AUTOINCREMENT` property..

Comment: I'm using SQLite3 with Python. I don't know , I read it online that we had to insert it that way. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: If you're just copying random stuff you should read this and decide if you *really* need the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify which columns you're inserting, e.g.:

```
filecur.execute("insert into File_Data(UID, FileName, Date_) values(?, ?, ?)",
                (uid, filename, today))
```

Note that you *could* insert the autoincrement field explicitly, e.g.:

```
filecur.execute("insert into File_Data(FID_, UID, FileName, Date_) values (?, ?, ?, ?)",
                (fid, uid, filename, today))
```

But normally you wouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! :)